# how to get new response from a google form to different folders based on the form input value

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a form contains questions

1. BL number
2. Importer code
3. Upload file
   when each user submit response, files should be saved in different folders and folder name should be input value of question "BL number". how we can make it possible ?

Comment: Stackoverflow won't write the code for you, but you'll want to look at how to use the onformsubmit trigger with the result spreadsheet from your form, and then the GAS commands for moving files. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app

Comment: use `onSubmit` to handle file placement

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It heavily depends on how your form looks like.

Here is an example how it could be done.

Suppose you have a very simply form like this:

[image]

It has two 'namedValues': `Folder` and `File`, they will be used in the script below.

Next step: You have to add a 'linked' spreadsheet to the form.

[image]

In this spreadsheet you have to add this script:

```
// names and IDs of your destination folders

var folders = {
  'aaa' : '###', // <-- you have to change ### with a real ID
  'bbb' : '###',
  'ccc' : '###'
}

function move_file_to_folder(e) {

  // get folder ID from folders object
  var folder_id = folders[e.namedValues['Folder'][0]]; // <-- the name from the named value 'Folder'

  // get file ID from the form
  var file_id = e.namedValues['File'][0].split('id=')[1]; // <-- the url from the named value 'File'

  // move the file into the folder
  DriveApp.getFileById(file_id).moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_id));
}


// this function should be run just once to install the trigger

function install_OnFormSubmitTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('move_file_to_folder')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onFormSubmit()
      .create();
}
```

After that you have to run the function `install_OnFormSubmitTrigger()` to install the trigger.

Probably it makes sense to run the function `move_file_to_folder()` as well, in order to get the propper access. It will get you an error. Don't mind. Keep calm and carry on.

Now, every time you submit the form the uploaded file will go into a folder with respective name ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc' in my example).