# How to move files uploaded from Google Forms to a specific folder based on responses?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms, google-apps

I have a Google Form with seven questions.

The first question is a text entry box for "ID". Respondents will be instructed to write a value from 1 to 50.

The remaining six questions are optional file upload fields corresponding to six different forms that may be uploaded.

I would create (if a script couldn't do this manually) a folder structure with 50 parent folders for each ID, and 6 subfolders for each different form.

How would I write a script that would evaluate form responses to place uploaded files in the designated form's subfolder within the parent ID folder?

I see some sample scripts online that move uploaded files to folders, but I'm having a hard time finding scripts that conditionally move folders based on responses.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69132539/how-to-get-new-response-from-a-google-form-to-different-folders-based-on-the-for

Comment: What is the code you have tried so far? Whenever possible, you need to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way

Comment: @Rubén I'm not sure if my old answer by that link is the actual answer on this particular question. It's need to clarify before closing the question.

Comment: @YuriKhristich If the OP confirms that the linked Q/A is doesn't answer this question and updates it accordingly it can be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using Drive API

```
Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": folder.getId()}]}, file.getId());
```